# insert and update triggers do not fire on replicated table

Tags: postgresql, replication, trigger, change-data-capture

I have created a publication and a subscription on two servers with `wal_level = logical` in my postgresql.conf. Replication is functioning normally. My problem is to track changes in the replicated table, so I`ve created a function and a trigger on` INSERT`and`UPDATE`. However my created trigger does not fire when changes are made in my replicated table.

I've found a similar problem and a solution in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671816/14028966) here, but when I do this:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ENABLE ALWAYS TRIGGER <trigger_name>;
```

my replication process stops working and I see `pg_replication_slots.active = f` in my publisher server.

I would like to avoid solutions with pgAudit, Kafka and others like and stick with PostgreSQL tools if possible because I am a novice and I doubt that I can handle too many new tools at once.

I can provide you all the commands issued on both servers if that would be of any help. Thanks!

In my log file I see that the relation where the changes should be stored does not exist:

```
relation "mtable_history" does not exist at character 13
```

Character 13 is a position in a query:

```
INSERT INTO mtable_history VALUES ...
```

However, it does exist in `\dt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for security reasons, the `search_path` is set empty during replication replay. So you have to qualify the object names with the schema in the trigger function, for example `public.mtable_history`.